“Troubleshooting 502 Error in API Gateway’s HttpIntegration”
I have a laravel app and now I implemented aws api-gateway using CDK and SAM to test in the local environment. I was able to create lambdas and communicate with laravel via Axios, for example for login / logout routes and this works perfect.
Now I need a proxy and for that I added a httpIntegration:
const adminProxyIntegration = new apigateway.HttpIntegration('http://laravel-back.app', {
      httpMethod: 'ANY',
      options: {
        connectionType: apigateway.ConnectionType.INTERNET,
      },
      proxy: true,
    });

const adminProxyResource = api.root.addResource('{proxy+}');
adminProxyResource.addMethod('ANY', adminProxyIntegration);

This generates this route: http://127.0.0.1:3000/{proxy+} [DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
but when I tried to access to /api/laravel-test I got "GET /v1/api-gateway/test HTTP/1.1" 502 ".
I tried different ways, using localhost / using ngrok and anything works, and it's only with the proxy because the other routes with axios work perfectly.
